# Horizontal jquery scroller using position:absolute; with constant scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, horizontal-scrolling, absolute

I've managed to get this far and it works great for solid width divs but can't work out how to manipulate it to work when the width of the div changes.

**Question: How do I make this function take into account the different div widths after each 'round'?**

```
var horizontalScroller = function($elem) {
    var left = parseInt($elem.css("left"));
    var temp = -1 * $('#horizontalScroller li').width();
    if(left < temp) {
        left = $('#horizontalScroller').width();
        $elem.css("left", left);
    }
    $elem.animate({ left: (left-60) }, 2000, 'linear', function () {
      horizontalScroller($(this));
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $("#horizontalScroller li").each(function () {
          $(this).css("left", i);
          i += $(this).width();
          horizontalScroller($(this));
    });

});
```

*Working example (with fixed width): http://jsfiddle.net/GL5V3/*
*Working example (with different widths): http://jsfiddle.net/wm9gt/*

Comment: What are you trying to do and what do you mean by "make it work"?

Comment: If you take a look at the jsfiddle, you'll see how the different widths are hitting/in each other.  This is what I am trying to avoid, therefore making it like the fixed width example.

Comment: well - I know that you're going to need to change i+=60 to something that reflects the individual widths of each list item.

Comment: It shouldn't have anything to do with the `(left-60)`, it's only when it has another 'round' to do, it all goes weird.

Comment: You're doing horizontal scrolling kind of strangely. I presume the requirements are horizontal wrapping and time based "movement" ?

Comment: Yes that's right. As you can see from the fixed width example, it works fine. I've found a lot of plugins have the same issue with different width scrollers, they tend to speed up or slow down depending on the width of the image. The aim here it to have a continuous scroller that can handle different width images at a constant speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this was mildly fun, understood how your code works, but before I did that...

I rewritten it to this: [(working fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/9ban8/)

```
function horizontalScroller(ulSelector) {
  var horizontalSpan=0;
  var collection=[];
  function animate(index) {
    var cur=collection[index];
    var left=parseInt(cur.elem.css('left'));
    if(left < cur.reboundPos) {
        left+=horizontalSpan;
        console.log(left);
        cur.elem.css('left',left);
    }
    cur.elem.animate(
      { left: (left-60) },
      2000,
      'linear',
      function () {animate(index)}
    );
  }
  $(ulSelector).find('li').each(function() {
    var $this=$(this);
    var width=$this.width();
    $this.css('left',horizontalSpan);
    collection.push({reboundPos: -1 * width, elem: $this});
    horizontalSpan+=width;
    animate(collection.length-1);
  });
  console.log(collection);
  console.log(horizontalSpan);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    horizontalScroller('#horizontalScroller');
});
```

Then I went back to your code and did this:

```
var horizontalSpan = 0;// swapped i for a "global" variable
var horizontalScroller = function($elem) {
    var left = parseInt($elem.css("left"));
    var temp = -1 * $elem.width();// updated to the correct width
    if(left < temp) {// now out of bounds is properly calculated
        left += horizontalSpan;// proper "wrapping" with just one addition
        $elem.css("left", left);
    }
    $elem.animate({ left: (left-60) }, 2000, 'linear', function () {
      horizontalScroller($(this));
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#horizontalScroller li").each(function () {
          $(this).css("left", horizontalSpan);// horizontalSpan!!!
          horizontalSpan += $(this).width();// horizontalSpan!!!
          horizontalScroller($(this));
    });
});
```

If you've got questions or want to tweak it a bit. I'd be happy you to help you along. But my hopes are that you will manage on your own.

P.S. My initial comment was rude, you're horizontal scrolling is ok *thumbs up* (but you were hoping the values for some of those `.width()` calls to be way different)

Comment: This is perfect, and exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much.  The bounty will be rewarded to you within the next 10 hours (as the site will not let me to this before then).

Comment: One questions I do have, what exactly is the -60 for on line 13 of your function and line 9 of my updated function?  And why is it 60?

Comment: 1. Isn't it from your initial function? 2. It's the new left we want to animate towards, it's basically saying move 60 pixels to the left in a 2 second time....

Comment: Yes you are right, it is from my original function.  I forgot I left it in there, but thought this would change depending on the width of the `li`?  Obviously changing this would change the speed, which I think is where I was confused.